# Why is Bard formatting math expressions incorrectly in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Bard is formatting math expressions incorrectly in Google Chrome browser. Latex extention is installed in the browser. But Bard formats math expressions like the following for example:

S = \frac{k}{4\pi} \int_M \operatorname{Tr} \left( A \wedge dA + \frac{2}{3} A^3 \right)

Any idea how to fix this?